# How can I use images from backend server?

Tags: javascript, html

I try to diplay an Image which is stored on the backend server.

When I use an URL from another site it works.

```html
<img src="https://www.qries.com/images/banner_logo.png">
```

But this does not work.

```html
<img src="127.0.0.1/files/94632-test.png"/>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Add a protocol (e.g. `http://`).

Comment: Try `files/94632-test.png` without localhost path.

Comment: You could also just prepend `//` to it: `//127.0.0.1/files/94632-test.png`  Then it'll use whatever protocol was used to load the page.  The main point is that without the root `//` on the URL path it's looking for a *folder* called `127.0.0.1` relative to the current page's URL.  (Hint: Use your browser's debugging tools to observe the network requests being made when the page loads.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks  deceze!

It worked with adding the protocol.

```html
<img src="http://127.0.0.1/files/94632-test.png"/>
```